# HTML.RenderAction from Different location?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have `[ChildActionOnly]` in my Controller called `_AllLinks`

I can use RenderAction if _AllLinks.cshtml is in my Controller Directory but I cannot use it if i try to put it in a different directory in VIEWS folder such as the following

```
Html.RenderAction("_AllLinks", "Home", new { Model = Model, Area = "Core/List/" });
```

Where Location of `_AllLinks.cshtml` is `Views/Core/Lists/`

How can i call Html.RenderAction if PartialView called _AllLinks is in a different folder?

Cheers

**EDIT**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult _AllLinks(List<Models.Links.MLink> Model)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Core/Lists/_AllLinks", Model);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can. You need to explicitly specify the full path to the view.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _AllLinks(List<Models.Links.MLink> Model)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Core/Lists/_AllLinks.cshtml",Model);
}
```

Make sure you use the full path **with the file extension** (`.cshtml`)

Also you should be calling the RenderAction with route values matching your action method signature.

```
<div>
    @{ Html.RenderAction("_AllLinks", "Home", new {model = Model}); }
</div>
```

Comment: No Luck I did the following `return PartialView("~/Views/Core/Lists/_AllLinks", Model);` and then called it like this `Html.RenderAction("_AllLinks", "Home", new { Model = Model, Area = "Core/List/" });`

Comment: It should work. Do you have a parameter called model in your action method which expects the same type as your main views model ? why are you passing the Area via route dictionary ?

Comment: Share your action method signature.

Comment: Please see at the bottom of the original post

Comment: You are missing the file extension when calling the View method. It should be the path with file extension (`.cshtml`) !!!!

Comment: Still  no luck, it still looks for the view inside my controller folder `[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult _AllLinks(List<Models.Links.MLink> Model)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Core/Lists/_AllLinks.cshtml", Model);
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156735/discussion-between-shyju-and-aliusman).

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
public PartialViewResult Language()
{
    return PartialView("Admin/Languages/_LanguageEditView");
}
```

`_LanguageEditView` is located at `Shared/Admin/Languages/` folder. I think, `Shared` is important for partial views.

Comment: It also works without "shared" folder, see the answer above